# MYSQL Import Failing because of `//`

Tags: wordpress, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a mysql file that seems to be breaking at some HTML/JS that is stored in the database.

Here are a few errors:

> [ERROR in query 178] You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '

and

> [ERROR in query 179] You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '}
>
> ```
> // ]]>
> </script>
>
> <script src="./js/tooltip.js" type=' at line 1 [ERROR in query 180]
> ```
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '}
>       /* ]]> */

and

> [ERROR in query 181] You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Table
>   './web_cms_prod/wp_redirection_logs'
>   is marked as crashed and should be re'
>   at line 1

Its a wordpress database if that matters, not sure why someone is storing HTML in the database, but I need to get it imported nonetheless.

Any ideas? Can I escape it somehow? A SED unix command would be nice as its a 9 meg file.

Comment: What did you export it from? It *should* have been escaped properly if it came from another database.

Comment: try changing the delimiter before running the code. put `delimiter ;` on the top of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the `//` but some quotes that appear before it.  You need to make sure that all of the quotes contained within your string values are escaped.

Comment: Any way to do that? Its thousands of lines and not my database

Comment: If you're familiar with PHP, you could write a quick script to pass your SQL statements through `mysql_real_escape_string()`.